# SQL Server 2008 - Insert into table error "An explicit value for the identity column in table..."

Tags: sql-server-2008, insert, identity-column

I've created a temp table by just copying all data from an existing table. In the original table there is an identity column `MemberNumber`.

Every month, I need to find any new entries in the original table by comparing if the `MemberNumber` exists or not in my temp table and if not then insert this into my temp table. But I get the following error

> *An explicit value for the identity column in table....*

How can I just insert the `MemberNumber` value as is without it being an identity?

How do I not have this column be an identity column in my temp table?

Thanks

Comment: please show your code, table definitions etc. Otherwise the answer is look up IDENTITY INSERT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the best way would be to re-create the temp table without the identity property.  But if you're not able to do that for some reason, note that you can insert values into an identity column, by using [`SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

`MemberNumber` shouldn't be an identity column in your temp table since it is in essence foreign key reference to another table.  It should just be a not null integer column.